# SWIFT ARKIT detect the hand and nails, and place the object on the nails?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, arkit, swift5

I would like to know how to detect a person’s hand and nails, and then use ARKIT to place an object on her nails. Frankly, I’ve been looking for information about it for several days in Google, I haven’t found anything that could help me. I would really appreciate if you could help me! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: There are a lot related to ARKIT, if you know/sure this the way you want to do your task here is the example with the tutorial.
But please keep in mind that here you have to be precise and show us what have you tried so far and what is not working for you (Better to provide code snippet)

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-started-with-ar-in-swift-the-easy-way-7399fe1c82f5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to create a machine learning model using Apple's CreateML with images of fingernails and hands to train your app to recognize fingernails and hands and then use CoreML to transfer that recognition to ARKit where you can possibly use it place the object on the nails and hands. I understand that can be a lot to do so for a simpler start to solving your problem Apple has native image recognition functions that you can start experimenting with. Not sure if that necessarily solves your exact problem in recognizing fingernails and hands but at least it's a start.

Check below

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/tracking_and_altering_images

Comment: maybe you could also recommend me some tutorials about it, I would highly appreciate your help and definitely tick your answer as correct. thank you!

Comment: Sure @Daniel I just provided you a full project from Apple that you can download in that link that does something similar to what you're trying to do. Here's a tutorial that you may find useful though 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySYFZwkZoio

Comment: I don't understand why you gave the link for Tracking and Altering Images in your answer? How is it connected to what I am trying to do?